# How to train a reverse embedding, like vec2word?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, theano, caffe, pytorch

how do you train a neural network to map from a vector representation, to one hot vectors? The example I'm interested in is where the vector representation is the output of a `word2vec` embedding, and I'd like to map onto the the individual words which were in the language used to train the embedding, so I guess this is `vec2word`?

In a bit more detail; if I understand correctly, a cluster of points in embedded space represents similar words. Thus if you sample from points in that cluster, and use it as the input to `vec2word`, the output should be a mapping to similar individual words?

I guess I could do something similar to an encoder-decoder, but does it have to be that complicated/use so many parameters?

There's this [TensorFlow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/word2vec), how to train `word2vec`, but I can't find any help to do the reverse? I'm happy to do it using any deeplearning library, and it's OK to do it using sampling/probabilistic.

Thanks a lot for your help, Ajay.

Comment: You're interested in language modeling, correct? Do the examples in the [TensorFlow RNN tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/recurrent) help?

Comment: Hi @AllenLavoie, thanks for the pointer. No the TF examples did'nt help that much - maybe you want to up date them with something on this question? Someone else helped me though. It's quite simple actually, you just take the, matrix vector product of the embedding weights, and the `query` vector, and then rank the vector you get from that product - I'm not explaining that well, but look here - https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py#L281.  Thanks, Ajay

Answer (score 1):

One easiest thing that you can do is to use the nearest neighbor word. Given a query feature of an unknown word `fq`, and a reference feature set of known words `R={fr}`, then you can find out what is the nearest `fr*` for `fq`, and use the corresponding `fr*` word as `fq`'s word.